# How do changes in α affect β for a BJT?

Tags: transistors, bjt

> Show that for a transistor with α close to unity, if α changes by a small per-unit amount (Δα / α), the corresponding per-unit change in β is given approximately by
>
> $$\frac{\Delta\beta}{\beta}\approx\beta\left(\frac{\Delta\alpha}{\alpha}\right)$$

I know the equations:

$$\alpha=\frac{\beta}{1+\beta} \textrm{ and } \beta=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$

But am unsure what Δα / α really means. I tried assuming that it was a linear approximation, but after lengthy scribbling, that led me nowhere:

$$\alpha'=\alpha\left(1+\frac{\Delta\alpha}{\alpha}\right)$$

Comment: You're on the right track. Now try using the substitution \$\frac{\beta'}{1+\beta'}=\alpha'\$.

Comment: Notice that for "alpha close to unity",  1-alpha is almost 1 too.

Comment: @JimmyB I thought "unity" meant \$\alpha \approx 1\$?

Comment: That's right, edited my comment to make it more clear.

Comment: So, doesn't that make \$\alpha \approx 1 \implies 1 - \alpha \approx 0\$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to @Chu's answer, use sensitivity analysis to determine \$\beta\$'s sensitivity to changes in \$\alpha\$.

$$
S_{\alpha}^{\beta} =\lim_{\Delta \alpha \to 0}\left \{ \frac{\Delta \beta / \beta}{\Delta \alpha / \alpha} \right \}=\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \alpha} = \frac {1}{1-a}
$$

Now, as @Chu has already mentioned, since \$\alpha \approx 1\$ (via the problem statement),

$$
\frac {1}{1-\alpha} \biggm \rvert_{\alpha \approx 1} \approx \frac {\alpha}{1-\alpha} = \beta
$$

So,

$$
\frac {\Delta \beta}{\beta} 
= \frac {1}{1-\alpha} \: \frac {\Delta \alpha}{\alpha}
\approx \frac {\alpha}{1-\alpha} \: \frac {\Delta \alpha}{\alpha} 
= \beta \: \frac {\Delta \alpha}{\alpha}
$$

for \$\alpha \approx 1\$ as \$\Delta \alpha \to 0\$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ \beta + \Delta \beta =\dfrac{\alpha +\Delta \alpha}{1-(\alpha +\Delta \alpha)}$$

then
$$  \Delta \beta =\dfrac{\alpha +\Delta \alpha}{1-(\alpha +\Delta \alpha)}-\dfrac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$

Do the subtraction; divide both sides by \$\beta\$; then note that, since \$\alpha\approx 1\$ :
 $$\dfrac{1}{1-\alpha}\approx \dfrac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\beta$$